# Java EE Objects Monitoring Tools

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have a very large Java EE application which runs on tomcat. Unfortunatelly lately i get heap space and memory-leaks errors.

So i was wondering if there is a tool to help me monitor my application and to give me a visual presentation of each object and more importantly how many memory it takes.

Comment: Give it a try: http://plumbr.eu/

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm.. If you are "just" running Tomcat, you don't have a Java EE application. You have a servlet application.

Anyway: [JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) comes to mind. Or [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/).

These are all pretty general, so no precise object counting. For that, you will have to roll in something by yourself.

You may want to check out [java-allocation-instrumenter](https://code.google.com/p/java-allocation-instrumenter/) and [Lambda Probe](http://www.lambdaprobe.org/). I have never used them but they sound interesting.